# htaccess https for several subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web, virtualhost, virtual-hosts

I have virtual hosts

```
<VirtualHost 10.10.10.10:80>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@server.com
     ServerName server.com
     ServerAlias subdomain-a.server.com subdomain-b.server.com subdomain-c.server.com subdomain-d.server.com
     DocumentRoot /srv/www/server.com/public_html/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 10.10.10.10:443>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@server.com
     ServerName server.com
     ServerAlias subdomain-a.server.com subdomain-b.server.com subdomain-c.server.com subdomain-d.server.com
     DocumentRoot /srv/www/server.com/public_html/
</VirtualHost>
```

I want to force visitors use https for subdomain-a and subdomain-c. Visitors of subdomain-b and subdomain-d could use http and https. How to configure .htaccess?

Comment: There is plenty of example here on SO. Try looking for one that matches a specify host with `%{HTTP_HOST}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(subdomain-a|subdomain-c)\.server\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```